# Text when printing sometimes overlaps footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code that returns print sheets with a page break. Sometimes the text goes to the second page and overlaps the footer and header and it cannot. I show an example:

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "552",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "552", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "552",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "562", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "562",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
];

var data1 = [
   {Id_Linha: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "camisola", },
   {Id_Linha: "562", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "calças", },,
];

var results = data.concat(data1).reduce(function(results, item) {
  var id = item.Id || item.Id_Linha;
  (results[id] = results[id] || []).push(item);
  return results;
}, {});


$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {
  var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(id => {
    linha += `<div style="page-break-inside:avoid;"> 
    
    <div class="col-md-4 page-header">
                              <p class="taman1">zzzzzzzzzzzz, 29 de novembro de 2022</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="teste" style="clear:both"></div>
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 25%;">Assunto: Aviso de incumprimento</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman1">xxxxxxxxxxxx, 29 de novembro de 2022</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 5%;">Exmo Senhor(a),</p>
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" border="1">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Data de Vencimento</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;
    results[id].forEach(item => {
      var idValue = item.Id || item.Id_Linha; // Use the "Id" property if it exists, otherwise use the "Id_Linha" property
      var valor = item.valor;
      var descricao = item.Descricao;
      linha += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${idValue}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
    })
    linha += `</tbody></table>
    <div>
                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 5%;">Para o efeito, estabelecemos o prazo de 8 dias contados.</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Mais informamos que, no caso dos montantes não forem pagos no prazo fixado.</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Na eventualidade do pagamento já tiver sido efetuado, agradecemos que considerem .</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Sem outro assunto de momento, subscrevemo-nos,</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 5%; margin-right: -15%;">De V. Exas.</p>
                            <p class="taman1" style="text-align:center; margin-right: -15%;">Atenciosamente</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rodap">
                            <p class="taman2">xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xx - xxxx-xxx xxxxxxxx</p>
                            <p class="taman2">xxxxxx: xx xxx xx xx </p>
                            <p class="taman2">E-mail: xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.pt</p>
                            </div>
    </div>`;
  });
  $('#minhaDiv3').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
  
  
  
  document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis")); 
}

function printElement(elem) {

    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    
    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    console.log($printSection);
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();

}
```

```css
.rodap {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  text-align:center !important;
}

@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none !important;
  }

}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden !important;
  }
  .page-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
 
  .rodap {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 33% !important;
  }
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible !important;
  }
  
  #printSection {
    position:absolute !important;
    left:0 !important;
    top:0 !important;
    
  }
  .espac {
    line-height: 0.5 !important;
  }
  .taman{font-size: 24px;}
  .taman1{font-size: 22px;}
  .taman2{font-size: 16px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 

<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">Teste</button>

<section id="s3">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv3">
    <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrint" style="text-align:right;">Print</button>

      <div id="printThis">
        <div class="row pagmfalta">

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

You are doing the page break correctly, but the content overlaps the header in case the same letter occupies more than one page and overlaps the footer. I want the content to never overlap the header or footer.
I needed to understand if it is possible to solve this problem, can anyone give any tips?

Please, can anyone help me?

I'm trying this solution:

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "552",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "552", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "552",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "562", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "562",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
];

var data1 = [
   {Id_Linha: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "camisola", },
   {Id_Linha: "562", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "calças", },,
];

var results = data.concat(data1).reduce(function(results, item) {
  var id = item.Id || item.Id_Linha;
  (results[id] = results[id] || []).push(item);
  return results;
}, {});


$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {
  var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(id => {
    linha += `<div style="page-break-inside:avoid;"> 
    
                            <div class="col-md-4 page-header">
                              <p class="taman1">zzzzzzzzzzzz, 29 de novembro de 2022</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 25%;">Assunto: Aviso de incumprimento</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman1">xxxxxxxxxxxx, 29 de novembro de 2022</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 5%;">Exmo Senhor(a),</p>
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" border="1">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Data de Vencimento</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;
    results[id].forEach(item => {
      var idValue = item.Id || item.Id_Linha; // Use the "Id" property if it exists, otherwise use the "Id_Linha" property
      var valor = item.valor;
      var descricao = item.Descricao;
      linha += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${idValue}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
    })
    linha += `</tbody></table>

                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 5%;">Para o efeito, estabelecemos o prazo de 8 dias contados.</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Mais informamos que, no caso dos montantes não forem pagos no prazo fixado.</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Na eventualidade do pagamento já tiver sido efetuado, agradecemos que considerem .</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Sem outro assunto de momento, subscrevemo-nos,</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 5%; margin-right: -15%;">De V. Exas.</p>
                            <p class="taman1" style="text-align:center; margin-right: -15%;">Atenciosamente</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rodap">
                            <p class="taman2">xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xx - xxxx-xxx xxxxxxxx</p>
                            <p class="taman2">xxxxxx: xx xxx xx xx </p>
                            <p class="taman2">E-mail: xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.pt</p>
                            </div>
    </div>`;
  });
  $('#minhaDiv3').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
  
  
  
  document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis")); 
}

function printElement(elem) {

    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    
    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    console.log($printSection);
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();

}
```

```css
.rodap {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  text-align:center !important;
}

@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none !important;
  }

}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden !important;
  }
  .page-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:20px; 
    padding-right:20px;
    height: auto;  //height is set to auto
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
  }
  .rodap {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f89;
    line-height: 0.5 !important;
  }
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible !important;
  }
  
  #printSection {
    position:absolute !important;
    left:0 !important;
    top:0 !important;
    
  }

  .taman{font-size: 24px;}
  .taman1{font-size: 22px;}
  .taman2{font-size: 16px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 

<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">Teste</button>

<section id="s3">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv3">
    <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrint" style="text-align:right;">Print</button>

      <div id="printThis">
        <div class="row pagmfalta">

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This way it doesn't overlap the footer, but hides lines behind the footer. But I still have the header problem. Can anyone help resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I think the overlap issue is in this line  `<p class="taman1">xxxxxxxxxxxx, 29 de novembro de 2022</p>` because its inheriting from this class (taman1).
and if you hide from printing page it will appear correctly.
somthing like this :

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "552",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "552", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "552",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
    {Id: "545", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
   {Id: "562", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "562",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno",  },
];

var data1 = [
   {Id_Linha: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "camisola", },
   {Id_Linha: "562", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "calças", },,
];

var results = data.concat(data1).reduce(function(results, item) {
  var id = item.Id || item.Id_Linha;
  (results[id] = results[id] || []).push(item);
  return results;
}, {});


$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {
  var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(id => {
    linha += `<div > 
    
    <div class="col-md-4 page-header head_class">
                              <p class="taman0">zzzzzzzzzzzz, 29 de novembro de 2022</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="teste" style="clear:both"></div>
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 25%;">Assunto: Aviso de incumprimento</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman0">xxxxxxxxxxxx, 29 de novembro de 2022</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 5%;">Exmo Senhor(a),</p>
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" border="1">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Data de Vencimento</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;
    results[id].forEach(item => {
      var idValue = item.Id || item.Id_Linha; // Use the "Id" property if it exists, otherwise use the "Id_Linha" property
      var valor = item.valor;
      var descricao = item.Descricao;
      linha += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${idValue}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
    })
    linha += `</tbody></table>
    <div >
                            <p class="taman1" style="margin-top: 5%;">Para o efeito, estabelecemos o prazo de 8 dias contados.</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Mais informamos que, no caso dos montantes não forem pagos no prazo fixado.</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Na eventualidade do pagamento já tiver sido efetuado, agradecemos que considerem .</p>
                            <p class="taman1">Sem outro assunto de momento, subscrevemo-nos,</p>
                            
                            <p class="taman1" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 5%; margin-right: -15%;">De V. Exas.</p>
                            <p class="taman1" style="text-align:center; margin-right: -15%;">Atenciosamente</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="rodap">
                            <p class="taman2">xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx, xx - xxxx-xxx xxxxxxxx</p>
                            <p class="taman2">xxxxxx: xx xxx xx xx </p>
                            <p class="taman2">E-mail: xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx.pt</p>
                            </div>
    </div>`;
  });
  $('#minhaDiv3').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
  
  
  
  document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function () {
    printElement(document.getElementById("printThis")); 
}

function printElement(elem) {

    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
    
    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");
    
    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }
    console.log($printSection);
    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();

}
```

```css
@media screen {
  #printSection {
      display: none !important;
  }

}

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility:hidden !important;
  }
  .page-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
  }
  .content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:20px; 
    padding-right:20px;
    height: auto;  //height is set to auto
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
  }
  .rodap {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f89;
    line-height: 0.5 !important;
  }
  #printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible !important;
  }
  
  #printSection {
    position:absolute !important;
    left:0 !important;
    top:0 !important;
    
  }

  .taman{font-size: 24px;}
  .taman1{font-size: 22px;}
  .taman2{font-size: 16px;}
}
@media print {
  .taman0 {display:none;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 

<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">Teste</button>

<section id="s3">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv3">
    <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrint" style="text-align:right;">Print</button>

      <div id="printThis">
        <div class="row pagmfalta">

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```